# GGplot2 Add medians in two different part of the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, median

I am trying to plot median values into a graph for a single case study. Unfortunately, I cannot get the result I would like to have. Here's my code.

```
Rate <- c(8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 18, 15, 9, 8, 17, 19, 11, 11)
Phase <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Occasions <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
db4 <- data.frame(Occasions, Phase, Rate)

medians <- db4 %>% 
      group_by(Phase) %>% 
      mutate(M = median(Rate))

    ggplot(data = db4, aes(x = Occasions, y = Rate)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = Phase)) +
      geom_line(aes(group = Phase, color = Phase)) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = medians$M, colour = 'red') +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 8.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
      xlab("Occasions") +
      ylab("Ratings")
```

Below, you can find the plot that comes from this code. However, both median lines are currently red and extend across the whole plot. I would like to have the first red median line only in the left side of the graph and a second BLUE median line only in the right side of the graph. I also would like to add titles for the two sides which are "Baseline" and "Intervention"[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To clarify, you want the respective median lines to only be on their half of the graph? and to be the same red/blue colour as their phase?

Comment: Yes, your clarification is correct

Comment: Try using `+ facet_wrap(~Phase)` as a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this plot. I wouldn't use facets because you want to keep everything on one axis, but I wouldn't use two titles either. Instead, just relabel your legend to make clear which points are Baseline and which are Intervention.

To fix the median lines and prevent them crossing the whole plot, you need to use `geom_segment` instead of `geom_hline`. This also means you need to add some more columns to your `medians` data frame to provide the right inputs (start and end coordinates for the segments). I move `color = Phase` to the top `ggplot()` so `geom-segment` inherits and splits the two phases. Finally I made `geom_vline` use aesthetics for `xintercept` so its position isn't hardcoded (may or may not be ideal in your case).

```r
library(tidyverse)
db4 <- data.frame(
  Rate = c(8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 18, 15, 9, 8, 17, 19, 11, 11),
  Phase = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  Occasions = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
)

medians <- db4 %>% 
  group_by(Phase) %>%
  summarise(
    y = median(Rate),
    x_start = min(Occasions),
    x_end = max(Occasions)
    )

ggplot(data = db4, aes(x = Occasions, y = Rate, color = Phase)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(
    data = medians,
    mapping = aes(x = x_start, xend = x_end, y = y, yend = y)
    ) +
  geom_vline(
    mapping = aes(xintercept = median(Occasions)),
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "blue",
    size = 0.5
    ) +
  labs(x = "Occasions", y = "Ratings") + 
  scale_colour_hue(labels = c("Baseline", "Intervention"))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for your help and for your valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `facet_grid` with a free x scale.

To change `A` and `B` to `Baseline` and `Intervention` recode the column.

```
db4 <- data.frame(Occasions, Phase, Rate) %>% 
  mutate(Phase = recode(Phase, A = "Baseline", B = "Intervention"))

medians <- db4 %>% 
  group_by(Phase) %>% 
  mutate(M = median(Rate))

ggplot(data = db4, aes(x = Occasions, y = Rate)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Phase)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Phase, color = Phase)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = M), colour = 'red', data = medians) +
  facet_grid(~Phase, scales = "free_x") +
  xlab("Occasions") +
  ylab("Ratings")
```

[image]